# If a = 3i + 2j and b = -7i + 4j, find a + b as...

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

"Trig functions enable you to make mathematical models of vector quantities:"

If $\vec{a}$ = 3$\vec{i}$ + 2$\vec{j}$ and $\vec{b}$ = -7$\vec{i}$ + 4$\vec{j}$, find a + b as:

A) a sum of two components
B) a magnitude and angle in standard position

I'm not looking for an answer but I have no idea where to start, if somebody could just run me through the basics so I can figure it out that would be very helpful!

Comment: On [this site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) there is a guide to formatting mathematics on math.SE. In short, writing `$\vec{i}$` gives you $\vec{i}$. A longer example: `$\vec{a} = 3\vec{i} + 2\vec{j}$` gives $\vec{a} = 3\vec{i} + 2\vec{j}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\vec a+\vec b=(3\vec i+2\vec j)+(-7\vec i+4\vec j)=?$
Assume that the answer to part $a$ is $a\vec c+b\vec d$. Then the magnitude is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. Then use inverse trig to find the angle.

Answer (score 0):

Hint A: Treat $\vec{i}$ and $\vec{j}$ as normal variables (say $x$ and $y$) and compute the sum.

Hint B: if $\vec{v}=a\vec{i}+b\vec{v}$ then  $|\vec{v}|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.